# Increase integer out of database

Tags: php, mysql

I've a database where I get my id as integer. I want to use this value to rename new files. For that I've tried to grab the biggest number and add 1.
To simplify let's say id = 3.

If I do `echo ($zeile['id']) + 1;` I'm getting **31**.

If I do `echo intval($zeile['id']) + 1;` I'm getting **1** (intval(row['id']) is getting 0).

If I do `$i = $zeile['id']; $i = $i+1; echo $i;` I'm getting **1** ($i is getting 0).

If I do `var_dump($zeile['id']) + 1;`it's getting **NULL**

If I do `echo intval(trim($zeile['id'])) + 1;` I'm getting **1** again.

What else can I try to produce a real integer and increase it easily?

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Upload</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
  define ('MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost');
 define ('MYSQL_BENUTZER',  'root');
 define ('MYSQL_KENNWORT',  '');
 define ('MYSQL_DATENBANK', 'fotoupload');

 $db_link = mysqli_connect (
   MYSQL_HOST, 
  MYSQL_BENUTZER, 
  MYSQL_KENNWORT, 
  MYSQL_DATENBANK
 );
 
 $sql = "SELECT id FROM versuch1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
  
 $db_erg = mysqli_query( $db_link, $sql );
 if ( ! $db_erg ) {
   die('Ungültige Abfrage: ' . mysqli_error($db_link));
 }

 while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $db_erg)){
  echo 'ID:' . $zeile['id'] . '<br/>';
 }
 
  echo var_dump($zeile['id']) +1 ;
  
 mysqli_free_result( $db_erg );
   
?>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you verified that your query is working? If that 3 is in an integer column, adding 1 to it should be pretty foolproof. Can you var_dump the row you've fetched and show the output in your question?

Comment: can you please `var_dump($row['id'])` and add the output to your question, otherwise try this `intval(trim($zeile['id'])) + 1`, I'm wondering if you've got a string with whitespace.

Comment: How can I check if I got whitespace? Btw - database is definitively marked as `int`

Comment: Can you show the code and `var_dump($zeile['id']);`?

Comment: _it's getting NULL_ well I'm out, I've got no idea how you got a null here and 30 in the first one.

Comment: Oh man I got it: `echo intval ($zeile['id']);` has to be in the while brackets

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the `echo intval($zeile['id']) + 1;` into the while-loop.